# How to prevent the long enter button issue in chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

Hi i am using ajax chat in which if we click enter it trigger the submit button.if we click the enter button one times there is no issues.if we long press the enter button the submit call repetitively and the chat message saved multiple times.please help on this issue
sample jquery code:

```
$("#chat_message").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "#send-btn" ).click();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

html code:

```
<input type="text"  name="message" id="chat_message" >
 <button type="button" id="send-btn">Send</button>
```

Comment: Also check for the value of `$("#chat_message")`

Comment: use on keyup instead of keypress

Comment: @cheralathan  please check the html code the keyup is not applicable for this scenario.And i check that to it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply,And i got the solution,

```
 $("#chat_message").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
      if ($('#chat_message').val() != "") {
        $("#send-btn").click();
        $('#chat_message').val("");
     }
   return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the `keyup` event works perfectly in your case.

Please have a look at below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  //the keyup event
  $("#chat_message").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "#send-btn" ).click();

            return false;
        }
  });
  
  $( "#send-btn" ).on("click",function(){
    console.log($("#chat_message").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text"  name="message" id="chat_message" >
  <button type="button" id="send-btn">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```